# Make the custom viewcontroller cover the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, view, uinavigationbar, viewcontroller

I am showing a custom pop up over my main viewcontroller. For this I have created a viewcontroller in the storyboard (image shown), the corresponding class being as below.

[image]

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        self.showAnimate()
    }

    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished) {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my main viewcontroller, I show this pop up on a button click as follows:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup") as! PopUpViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

This makes the background of the main view controller black with opacity of 70% when the pop up is added. How can I make the navigation bar also have the same background effect?

I have tried updating:

```
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

in viewDidLoad() but did not work. Any possible solution?

Comment: Did you try like that `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.7)`          ?

Comment: @Ahmet Ustem I had tried like that as well but does not work. I have got the solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are adding the `popOverVC` as a subview to the view of your `mainViewController` that is embedded in `UINavitationController`. If that is the case, then it is only logical that the `popOverVC` does not overlay the navigationBar, because navigationBar is a subview of the `navigationController`, not of your `mainViewController`. To be able to overlay also the navigationBar, you will have to add that `popOverVC` to the `navigationController`:

```
// to make things a bit easier working with the optional self.navigationController
guard let navController = self.navigationController else { return }

let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "MainViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup") as! PopUpViewController
navController.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = navController.view.bounds
navController.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: navController)
```

Comment: May I request you to update
popOverVC.view.frame = self.navController.view.bounds
with
popOverVC.view.frame = navController.view.bounds
Your solution works, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I implemented your solution and its working. However, after dismissing the subview, the button (on nav bar) clicks are working but the views are not changing accordingly. How can i solve this?

Comment: @KushalShrestha did you remove the `popOverVC.view` from superview? that's only thing that comes to my mind now